# How to send VoIP calling between two android devices on Local WiFi?

Tags: android, voip, android-wifi

There are many questions that provide answer for streaming audio over WiFi, but I need to identify the device and send the stream only to the device which is called.

I'm a beginner and I want to know how to get the status of the device, that is whether it is on the network or whether it is already on a call or not and how to get notification that a call is being received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement VoIP on android using Doubango API available open source

Answer (score 0):

VoIP is not only the sound, but also, and most, the signaling.
There are many signaling protocols out there. for example: `SIP`, `H.323`.
In order to implement a VoIP client you should use one of these protocols. I personally recommend you to use `SIP` because it is much simpler and newer than `H.323`.

One of the open sources that allows you to do that is: [SIPDroid](http://sipdroid.org/)

Comment: I implemented the SIP protocol but now the question is how to do it without using the SIP API? Not all the phone's support SIP API, but still the application [Zoiper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoiper.android.app) is able to handle calls via a locally setup SIP server. Any idea how could that be done?